# No puedo ejecutar ni ver mis macros de Excel ni crear nuevos módulos

Tags: excel, vba

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente problema para ejecutar macros en Excel.

No puedo ejecutar mis macros desde la cinta de opciones y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al ingresar al editor de VBA aunque me aparecen mis módulos creados en la barra de proyectos al darles click no se abren.

Además al querer grabar una macro no me lo permite por que Excel se queda trabado y tengo que forzar el cierre del libro o me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De igual manera se bloquea si quiero crear un nuevo modulo desde el editor de VBA y tengo que forzar el cierre también.
En mi configuración de Excel mis macros si están habilitadas y mi Excel es Microsoft 365.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día. Al querer grabar una nueva macro me aparece el mismos error "La sintaxis de este nombre no es correcta". Pudiste solucionarlo? Gracias.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que era un problema con la actualización de la licencia así que elimine y volví a instalar y importe el respaldo que cree de todas mis macros.

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/403006)